# Print array returns "Array"

Tags: php

When I try to print this :

```
   $erros[] = array($divErro1,$divErro2);    
     foreach($erros as $testeste){
     $testeste = array($erros);
```

using `print_r` i get the correct values, but with that marker of array "Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => ...."

How can i get it to print without that marks? I tried `echo` but it returns the word "Array"

Comment: what exactly do you want it to echo? can you post the output of your `print_r()` ?

Comment: Hi, it prints a DIV. The output is this: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => MYDIVHERE [1] => ) )

Comment: @Jason most likely the OP wants a dump of the array, but without the formatting print_r does (`[]()=>` chars)

Comment: @MarcB. Exactly Marc B. that's exactly what I need, could you help me on that? :)

Answer (score 4):

Your `foreach` doesn't look right, try this:

```
foreach($erros as $testeste) {
     echo $testeste;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Alix it looks like this because i set the result to another array to display after a series of verifications and displays! :P

Comment: @Armando: Are you sure? The `foreach` seems equivalent to `$testeste = end($erros);`.

Comment: Missing a $ in the echo statement. there's most likely no constant named `testeste`

Comment: Yeap i saw that and fixed before replacing in my code! But I cant get it to work :\

Comment: @Armando: I'm sure that if you find the time to post a mockup of what you're trying to output someone could help you with less ambiguity.

Comment: @Marc: Indeed. @Galen: Thanks for fixing it up.